# Symmetric function (under rotation)

Tags: real-analysis

I have a maybe silly question...

Consider the case that $f(x)=f(\lVert x\rVert)$.

My question is if $f\equiv 1$ is such a function.

For example this is used here:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/626181/dirichlet-boundary-problem-and-volume-potential

I am wondering about the domain of definition... because $x$ seems to be a vector, and $\lVert x\rVert$ is a real number...

Comment: Why? I know it is maybe too easy. :-)

Comment: Note, i added the ...to make up the character number

Comment: What set kind of set is $x$ in, and what is $||x||$? Since you apply $f$ to both of these objects $x$ and $||x||$, am I to understand that they are both in the set serving as the domain of $f$?

Comment: I guess what you said was an abuse of notation. Lhs is a function of x, rhs is a function of norm of x, the argument you feed in the functions are different, so what you said technically makes no sense.

Comment: I think the title "(under rotation)" means there is a specific norm 1 vector $v$ some where and $||x||$ really mean $||x||v$. I'm more annoyed with $f\equiv 1$. Does this means $f$ is constant function $1$ or $f$ is identity or $f$ is almost everywhere constant $1$? Why is the $\equiv$ there?

Comment: It means f is a constant function.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely.  For any $x$, both $f(x)$ and $f(\lvert x\rvert)$ are precisely $1$, and are therefore equal.

Comment: Why is $f(\lVert x\rVert)=1$?

Comment: @math12 Because you said that no matter what you plug in to your function, you always get back $1$.

Comment: But $x$ is a vector, $\lVert x\rVert$ is a real number. How can that be that I can put both into the function?!

Comment: @math12 I was interpreting $x$ as a complex number, in which case this is perfectly fine.